# Parent-child process messaging with result

Tags: javascript, node.js, messaging, child-process

I want to isolate some login inside of a child process. The idea is pretty simple:

- I wait for some event inside of master process
- send a message to child process
- if child process are able to handle it, then receive a result
- if child process fails then, log erros and fork a new process

The problem here: messaging. So, I wrote a prototype solution bellow:

```
const minion = fork('./minion')

const setupSend = (emmiter) => {
  const pool = {}
  emmiter.on('message', ({id, msg}) => {
    pool[id](msg)
    delete pool[id]
  })
  const send = (msg) => {
    const id = getId()
    const refObj = {}
    const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
      refObj.resolve = resolve
    })
    pool[id] = refObj.resolve
    emmiter.send({id , msg})
    return p
  }
  return send
}

const send = setupSend(minion)

send('message to reverse').then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

and sample `minion` code:

```
process.on('message', ({id, msg}) => {
  process.send({id, msg: msg.split("").reverse().join("")})
});
```

It works but it doesn't handle the errors and exit cases. probably I will manage to write all the required logic, but it feels like I am inventing a wheel.

So, is there an easier way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what the question is. Are you looking for an existing library to handle spinning up and watching child processes? Also do you need to use child processes? Usually in Node.JS child processes/clustering tend just to be used as a way to scale an entire application, whereas simple tasks like this just use async behavior.

Comment: I don't need to spin up and watch the process. it's more about the message handling